# Getting DISTINCT values from 3 columns

Tags: sql, distinct

I have 1 single table with 3 columns say col1,col2,col3

VALUES:

```
col1 with values (in individual 3 rows) as a, b, c
col2 with values (in individual 3 rows) as b, c, d
col3 with values (in individual 3 rows) as c, d, e
```

AIM:

To get distinct list to populate in html drop down box (i.e i want a,b,c,d,e) in alphabetical order ?

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
Select col1 from table
UNION
Select col2 from table
UNION
Select col3 from table
```

Comment: Hi nnhtuan, i just tried as below which is like what u said : SELECT DISTINCT column FROM ( SELECT maincat as column FROM brands UNION SELECT cat2 as column FROM brands UNION SELECT cat3 as column FROM brands ) ORDER BY column ASC                   .... now how to fetch it in php ?

Comment: Did it run fine? I don't know much about php. But if it runs fine, you may have a returned list normally and you can use the recordset or anything like this. Sorry because I'm not familiar with php.

Comment: your code is working, but i m not able to finish and get results. Like how to get DISTINCT and then fetch ?

Comment: THIS WORKED !!!! >>>>>>> (select maincat as mix from brands) union (select cat2 from brands ) union (select cat3 from brands) order by mix ASC